# Doxygen php error

Tags: php, doxygen

I have a php (doxygen.php) file which I'd like to document. The problem is wen I run `doxygen doxygen.php` on linux it doesn't generate anything...index.html file is empty. I get

```
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `php' at line 1, file doxygen.php
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `does' at line 4, file doxygen.php
Warning: ignoring unknown tag `nothing' at line 4, file doxygen.php
....
```

It seems that it doesn't recognize the comments properly. My doxygen.php file has this:

```
<?php


/* does nothing
 * @param teste
 * @return null
 */
function foo($foo) {
    echo 'hi'.$foo;
    return null;
}

?>
```

Comment: what version of doxygen are you running?

Answer (score 1):

when using doxygen you have to set your comments off with

`/**` ...`*/`

or `/*!`...`*/`

see the doxygen ["documenting the code"](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#specialblock) page

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/**
 * does nothing
 *
 * @param teste
 * @return null
 */
```

Comment: must be something with doxygen config. Apart from using `/*` instead of `/**` your syntax looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to include file data. use this code instead:

```
/**
* @file
* Test file intended for doxygen testing
*/


/**
 * does nothing
 *
 * @param teste
 * @return null
 */

function foo($foo) {
    echo 'hi'.$foo;
    return null;
}
```

It will work. tested it with my doxygen.